# Finding first previous 0 from starting cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to count the number of cells between two cells that I need to find with vba.  The first cell is going to be in the same column as the current date today.  The column headers are left to right in date order (May 1st, May 2nd, May 3rd, etc..).  Once I find the column to begin with, I need to count the number of cells backwards that contain 0 until I find a cell without a 0.  So say I'm starting in column U, I need to count the number of contiguous cells with 0 until say column R has a 1.  My answer would then be 2 because columns T and S had 0's.

The issue I'm running into with the below code is that I'm trying to find first the column I'm supposed to be in based on the date (This part works).  Next I'm declaring the rowNum as the activecell row number (This part work).  Next I need to find which column to count backwards to (This part does not work).  I'm getting the same column number on the colNum FIND code as I am the colStart FIND code.

I'm not getting any errors, it just doesn't seem like it's finding the previous cell with 0 and is instead just giving me the same column.  I hope this is clear.  Let me know if you need any additional info.  Thanks everyone!

```
today = Date

colNum = Cells.Find(today, searchorder:=xlByRows, 
         searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column
rowNum = ActiveCell.Row
colStart = Cells.Find(0, after:=Cells(rowNum, colNum), 
           searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column
```

Comment: I see that you left an answer, since deleted, that you found your error. You can just delete this question.

Comment: Right I deleted the answer I left. Turns out I did not figure it out.

Comment: This would make more sense if you posted some sample data (perhaps a screen shot).  You're basing your  method on what *you* think Excel is capable of.  There's quite possibly a more logical way to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Please supply data , desired result and logic. Seems like you are finding a column then looping back through columns in description above but I couldn't see how you determined which row(s) to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Public Function countZeros(ws As Worksheet, rowNum As Long, colNum As Long, Optional stopColumn As Long = 1) As Long
Dim currentCol As Long
    countZeros = 0
    If colNum <= stopColumn Then Exit Function   'prevents going past a certain point (for example your label column)
    For currentCol = colNum - 1 To stopColumn + 1 Step -1
        If ws.Cells(rowNum, currentCol) = 0 Then
            countZeros = countZeros + 1
        Else
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next 'currentCol
End Function

Public Sub mySub()
Dim colNum As Long
Dim rowNum As Long
Dim output As String
Dim today
Dim rng As Range
    today = Date

    Set rng = Cells.Find(today, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Did not find todays date, make sure your active cell is in the right location"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    colNum = rng.Column
    rowNum = ActiveCell.Row
    output = "Total number of cells from " & Cells(rowNum, colNum).Address & " that have zeros: "
    output = output & CStr(countZeros(ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet, rowNum, colNum))
    MsgBox output
End Sub
```

With this data set:

[image]

you get the output:
`Total number of cells from $K$7 that have zeros: 6`